# x, y, z = " " >>> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Tags: python

I am totally new to Python and there is one thing that annoys me. 
I always receive a ValueError when I try the following command:
x, y, z = " "

The Output is:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

What I actually would like to do is, to declare the 3 variables x, y, z which should all be " ". I looked in the Internet and people say that x, y, z = True (https://blog.softhints.com/python-declare-multiple-variables/) should work (which does not in my case). Therefore I thought that x, y, z = " " should work as well. But it does not.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You have a single character string but you are trying to unpack it into 3 variables.

Comment: *I looked in the Internet and people say that x, y, z = " " should work* - I wonder where you saw that. You should really give more details to what you are actually trying to do because without it we can't really help you. What you are doing right now is trying to *unpack* an object into three variables. That is not possible because that object is a string with one character. If you meant to initialize all three variables to that value you should either do `x = y = z = " "` or `x, y, z, = "   "` (which is 3 spaces...)

Answer (score 2):

You're probably confusing with:

```
x = y = z = " "
```

Which is short for:

```
x = " "
y = " "
z = " "
```